# Band New Front Gear Shift Issue

Tags: chain, cassette, chainring, derailleur-front

I brought a bike a few days ago and barely rode it. Every time I did I noticed that the chain would slip in the front gear going to a larger chainring, in this case it's gear 2. 'Funny thing is I took my bike to Dick's where I got it from originally, the guy hoists it and tries the gears; they worked properly then. I even tried it myself after him and the suspended bike worked like as it should.

But when I took it for a short ride at home the same issue came back. I'm wondering if it's my use of the bike that's in error.

I uploaded a zipped file of pictures and one video to illustrate my issue. There are pictures to show what settings I had before shifting and there is a video showing me pedaling the bike where the chain slips. Any ideas? Please share, thank you.

[zip file of bike pedaling issue][1]
[1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QCro7b3LB4m6AnHMsuWwkkweb_XwEp4-/view?usp=share_link

---

Yeah I’ll try a direct link next time. Thanks for all of your suggestions.

I went riding yesterday and learned that I had to push the shift more for the front gears to upshift. I had a good ride and I hope for many more to come.

Comment: Hey man. No one is going to download a sketchy zip file like that. Post individual and direct links to the photos and someone with editing privileges will likely embed them directly in your post. Also, look up the term “derailleur limit screw”

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Note that there's a huge difference between spinning the cranks on a stand with no load on the chain, and cranking against a load when you're riding.  At a _minimum_ have one person put the brakes partially on and the other person use both hands to turn the cranks.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Individual links and uploading the video to a trusted platform would be appreciated. Can you specify what you mean by "slipping"? Chain drops when shifting to the large chainring or skipping teeth? I suspect the former, in this case the outer limit screw of the front derailleur needs adjustment, i.e. the outer plate should leave enough space that the chain doesn't rub in the highest gear but no more than that to prevent it from overshifting and the chain falling off.